# Why does Radiant incorrectly show Uniform distributions?

Tags: radiant

I ran a Uniform distribution with variable X1 that spans the values 0 to 1. I ran the simulation 100,000 times then graphed the distribution with 50 bins.

Uniform Distribution

[image]

I noticed that Bin 1 and Bin 50 show only half the counts of all the other bins (around 1000 instead of 2000). I thought this may have been because of how Radiant splits Bins so I graphed the distribution with other numbers of bins but the first and last bin always have half the counts as the other bins.

Why is the uniform distribution showing up like that? Shouldn't all bins be around the same amount?